# ContractNotFound for contract instantiation in e2e-test

Tags: ink

I am trying to instantiate multiple contracts in my e2e-test. For some reason it can only find one of my contracts and not the others. Uploading the contract resulted in the same error: `ContractNotFound`.

From looking at the [delegator example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main/delegator) where `additional_contracts` are provided, I wrote my tests:

```
#[ink_e2e::test( additional_contracts = "accumulator/Cargo.toml" )]
async fn test_accumulator () { .. }

#[ink_e2e::test( additional_contracts = "adder/Cargo.toml" )]
async fn test_adder () { .. }

#[ink_e2e::test( additional_contracts = "subber/Cargo.toml" )]
async fn test_subber () { .. }
```

But it can't find the `adder` & `subber` contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only adding the `additional_contracts` once solved the problem:

```
#[ink_e2e::test( additional_contracts = "accumulator/Cargo.toml adder/Cargo.toml subber/Cargo.toml" )]
async fn test_accumulator () { .. }

#[ink_e2e::test]
async fn test_adder () { .. }

#[ink_e2e::test]
async fn test_subber () { .. }
```